# running a 32 bit debug build dll in a win7 64 bit using C#

Tags: c#, 32bit-64bit

I have a third party 32 bit dll that am planning on running on win7 64 bit. I did some research and i found out i should change the platform to x86. I did that it and i still get this error.

"**Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'Sensor.Data, Version=2013.3.4972.15254, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=****************' or one of its  dependencies. Strong name validation failed. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8013141A)**

Comment: What have you tried? Have you tried the top results from Googling for [strong name validation failed](http://goo.gl/3j8q1R)? (They helped me when I had this issue.)

Comment: Hint: **Strong name validation failed**

Comment: You just got a bad copy of the DLL.  Ask for another one.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try searching for the error online? Here is the first hit I got for an MSDN blog with a workaround.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/keithmg/archive/2012/03/20/strong-name-validation-failed-exception-from-hresult-0x8013141a.aspx

You may want to ask the third party to provide a fully signed DLL.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the `Sensor.Data` assembly is 32-bit.

If you have a 32-bit process, all the loaded DLLs and modules need to be 32-bit as well.